# Firefox extension to open mailto in Hotmail?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I used to use a Firefox extension which opened mailto links in one of the popular web based emails systems like Hotmail. I can't locate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow [this](http://www.techsupportforum.com/alternative-computing/mozilla-firefox-browsers/322003-solved-making-hotmail-default-mailto-firefox-3-a.html) short tutorial:

> 1. Type **about:config** into your location bar and hit enter. If you've
>      never edited used about:config before,
>      you'll see a warning.
> 2. Click *I'll be careful, I promise!* This will bring you to the
>      about:config window.
> 3. In the filter field type **gecko**. Double click the first entry
>      **gecko.handlerService.allowRegisterFromDifferentHost**
>      to change the value to **true**.
> 4. Copy and paste the text between the following text into the location bar
>      and hit enter:
>      `javascript:navigator.registerProtocolHandler('mailto','http://hotmail.msn.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s','Hotmail');`
> 5. You will see an information bar drop down at the top of the window.
>      Click *Add Application.* You've
>      finished installing the Hotmail
>      protocol now you just need to select
>      it.
> 6. Go to **Firefox>Preferences>Applications**, if
>      you are using a Mac, or
>      **Tools>Options>Applications**, if you are
>      using Windows. Now scroll down the
>      list by content type and find **mailto**.
>      In the drop-down menu to the right
>      select *Use Hotmail*.
> 7. Next, return to about:config.
> 8. If the warning comes up again, click *I'll be careful, I promise!*
> 9. In the filter field type **gecko**, and double click the first entry
>      **gecko.handlerService.allowRegisterFromDifferentHost**
>      to change the value back to **false**.

Answer (score 0):

If you also use greasemonkey you can use http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/56873 which does what you want.